# Button not clicking while leaving textarea focus

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a message space with the response field nice and small at the bottom. When the user clicks in, it expands. However, when focused, if I then go to click my button, it looses focus - as expected, but the button isn't triggered, I have to click it again. How can I best resolve this?

```css
.wrap {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

textarea {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 150px;
}

.fancy-button {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <div class="fancy-button" onclick="alert('click');">
</div>
```

Comment: yes, because the first click leave the `textarea:focus` and only the second it's "free" to click in other in other places.

Comment: You could use a javascript solution here to add a class to the textarea when in focus and then when it is not in focus check to see if there is any text in the the textarea, if so keep the class and if not remove the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that when you click, the button is not *technically* in this place but only *visually*. If you add a wrapper that cover all the space you may be able to catch the click from the first time.

While you are having the **fast** transition the browser is calculating and **updating** the position of the button; thus your click is outside the area of the button.

*You may also notice in this solution that if you click below the button the alert may not be triggered because of the same reasons. The wrapper is having its height decreasing rapidly and the click may be outside.*

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

textarea {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 150px;
}
.wrap > div {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
}
.fancy-button {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div onclick="alert('click');">
    <div class="fancy-button" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you only decrease the transition time you may also be able to catch the click the first time:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height 2s ease;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 150px;
}

.fancy-button {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div onclick="alert('click');" class="fancy-button">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also keep the duration and add a delay:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height .2s ease;
  transition-delay:0.1s;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 150px;
  transition-delay:0s;
}

.fancy-button {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div onclick="alert('click');" class="fancy-button">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: transition-delay did the trick thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this for you can works, because I don't know your needs, but if you use `hover` instead of `focus` the button is free to be clicked

```css
.wrap {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

textarea {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

textarea:hover {
  height: 150px;
}

.fancy-button {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <a class="fancy-button" onclick="alert('click');"><a/>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be good if can keep the focus but when unhover lose the focus ... as actually we may have unwanted transition on hover.

Comment: yes sure your answer are perfect, otherwise we have to use some js for make the animation.